# How to validate token from url request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have the following algorithm to check if the request was correct:

```
from aiohttp import BasicAuth

class A:
    def __init__(
        self,
        user_name: str,
        password: str,
        ...
    ):
        self._auth_header = BasicAuth(login=user_name, password=password).encode()

    async def handle_request(self, request):
        if not self.is_authorized_request(request):
            return Response(status=HTTPUnauthorized.status_code)

        ...
        return Response(status=HTTPOk.status_code)

    def is_authorized_request(self, request) -> bool:
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization")
        return auth == self._auth_header
```

But now I need to change the authentication to Token based authentication instead of login credentials. Because customer do not have the ability to use login credentials.

So I need to configure token authentication as part of the URL.
What is the best way of doing that?

I'm thinking about extracting `api_token` from the url and checking:

```
if my_token != api_token: 
   return Response(status=HTTPUnauthorized.status_code)
```

But Im not sure about that solution.

Comment: Use this [middleware](https://github.com/hzlmn/aiohttp-jwt)